# Serialized connection using Socket Programming

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to make a loop of communicating nodes passing very low level messages and I was wondering whether socket programming would be a good fit for my purpose. I will explain what I intend to do below:

Consider three nodes A, B, C.

1. Node A generates some data and sends it to B.
2. Node B receives this data, does some computation and sends it to C.
3. Node C receives this data, does some computation and sends it back to A.

To make it work, I was thinking of having all nodes as both client and servers.
Client A ----> Server B [After Computation] Client B ---> Server C [After Computation] Client C---> Server A

My question is that would this work? Or is there a major flaw in my thought process?

Thank you all :)

Comment: That depends a lot on the size of the data that's being passed about and the performance characteristics your application needs...

Comment: The only major flaw, aside from the lack of so much detail, sample code and no actual problems being experienced and all things being hypothetical, I'd say, is the existence of three nodes instead of one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid stackoverflow is not a good place for such question, this is "direct question -> direct answer" site. But here are some my thoughts:

It is weird architecture i must say. It could work this way, but how do you want to run client and server at the same node? No matter if they are 2 threads or 2 processes or even 2 applications, you will have to deal with communication between them.

You can also try to do peer-to-peer communication through UDP, but that's not going to be easier.

Consider alternative having server at node B offering service "some computation 1",
server at node C offering "some computation 2" and then client at node A, which will first query server B with the initial data, and after receiving response query server C with the returned data.